# steps needed for dropping a production tables' column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have this table as below and I want to remove the last column `DESCRIPTION_EXTENDED`. It is used in newer version of app but I want to keep the orig. as it was.

What is the process to remove this column?

I understand to use `ALTER` and `DROP` but do I have to something else?

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [ID]
,[FACILITY_KEY]
,[FIRST_LEVEL_CAT]
,[SECOND_LEVEL_CAT]
,[UNIQUE_KEY]
,[DESCRIPTION]
,[ACTIVE]
,[ORIG_ID]
,[COLOR]
,[PARENT_ID]
,[ADDRESS]
,[PHONE]
,[COMMENTS]
,[DESCRIPTION_EXTENDED]
FROM [DPRO2].[OGEN].[SCH_C_RESOURCES]
```

Comment: Step 0: backup. Step 0b: test backup...

Comment: just check every place where it may be used in your application before dropping...

Comment: "but I want to keep the orig. as it was" You want both app versions to be able to use the same table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Makue sure to take a backup of your entire table !

```
select * into [DPRO2].[OGEN].[SCH_C_RESOURCES_bkup] from [DPRO2].[OGEN].[SCH_C_RESOURCES]
```

then drop it !